# How can be send additional info on a form with several buttons on Symfony2?

Tags: jquery, forms, symfony

I recently started to use several buttons on a form, taking advantage of the `isclicked ()` method and the validation groups specified for each button.
It was working fine until I needed to ask for an additional info at the time the user pressed a specific button.

The thing is: Whenever I do something in jQuery on the click event of the button or the submit event of the form, it somehow prevents Symfony from knowing the button which was pressed, so it says that the clickedButton is null.

For example, when I do: `$form->getClickedButton()->getName()` I get this error:

> "Error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object"

Even if I just do this:

```
$("form").submit( function()
{
    $("button[type='submit']").attr("disabled", true);
});
```

The puzzling thing to me is that I have seen here advises of doing this kind of thing:

```
$(this).append('<button />').attr('type', 'hidden').attr('name', "something").attr('value', "something");
```

on the submit event, but when I do it, I don't seem to find that information on the request back in my controller.

How can I achieve sending additional info at the same time with the clicked button?

Answer (score 0):

The clicked button is determined using submitted data, if button name is presented in `POST` or `GET` then the button is marked as `clicked = true`.

Now, in your javascript snippet you are disabling button(s) and disabled fields/inputs won't be presented in submitted data, therefore, sf2 is not able to determine which button has been clicked.

As someone else already suggested use a hidden field, BUT add it to your form **first**, and then fill it with information using javascript as required.

Comment: As mentioned, a disabled button won't show in POST or GET but a hidden button will show up.